# What does delta to the k power mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do you use a recurrence to calculate delta to the kth power times a_n for k = 1,2,3,4. What does delta to the k mean?

Comment: Do you mean $\Delta$? Search for finite derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence.  (The lower bound of the index need not be $1$.)

The [first difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_equation#Relationship_to_difference_equations_narrowly_defined) of $(a_n)$ is 
$$  \Delta (a_n) = (a_{n+1}-a_n)_n  \text{,}  $$
the sequence of differences between elements of the sequence.  For instance, if $(a_n)_n = (n)_n$, the sequence of counting numbers, $\Delta (a_n) = ( (n+1) - n)_n = (1)_n$.

One can take repeated differences, noted by the number of applications of $\Delta$, for instance, \begin{align*}
\Delta^2 ((n)_n) &= \Delta \left( \Delta ((n)_n) \right)  \\
    &= \Delta \left( (1)_n \right)  \\
    &= (1-1)_n  \\
    &= (0)_n  \text{.}
\end{align*}

More generally, the $k^\text{th}$ difference of $(a_n)_n$ is
$$  \Delta^k (a_n)_n = \Delta^{k-1} \left( \Delta (a_n) \right)_n  $$
(and one recursively applies this rule, a total of $k$ times, to write the new sequence in terms of the old sequence.  For example, \begin{align*}
\Delta^2 (a_n) &= \Delta \left( \Delta(a_n) \right)  \\
    &= \Delta \left( a_{n+1} - a_n \right)  \\
    &= \left( a_{n+2} - a_{n+1} \right)_n - \left( a_{n+1} - a_n \right)_n  \\
    &= (a_{n+2} - 2 a_{n+1} + a_n)_n  \text{.} 
\end{align*}